# How to force SSL on some URLs using restlet on Heroku

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, jetty, restlet

I have a restlet-based app running on heroku that I want to use SSL. I have enabled the basic "piggyback" ssl option, so it accepts ssl connections -- almost there! However, I want some (actually, probably all) URLs to only work if the user connects via ssl. As it is now (I am told) Heroku converts SSL to non-ssl calls and sets the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO to https, so I think I need to deal with this in restlet, but I'm not sure how. I see the Redirector class, but it's not clear to me if I can use this class to solve this problem.

Note: I was previously running my app using GAE, which used a servlet container, so I could specify "CONFIDENTIAL" in web.xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the information out of the HTTP request headers and then decide if you want to throw an error or redirect:

```
    Form requestHeaders = (Form) this.getRequest().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");

    boolean secure = false;
    if (requestHeaders.getValues("x-forwarded-proto") != null) {
        secure = requestHeaders.getValues("x-forwarded-proto").contains("https");
    }
```

Expanding on this you can create a Filter that can easily be applied to a route.  A complete code example is [on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesward/restlet-template/tree/ssl_verify).  But here is the basic SecureFilter:

```
public class SecureFilter extends Filter {

    private boolean doRedirect;

    public SecureFilter(Context context, Restlet next) {
        super(context);
        doRedirect = false;
        setNext(next);
    }

    public SecureFilter(Context context, Restlet next, boolean doRedirect) {
        super(context);
        this.doRedirect = doRedirect;
        setNext(next);
    }

    public SecureFilter(Context context, Class<?> next) {
        super(context);
        doRedirect = false;
        setNext(next);
    }

    public SecureFilter(Context context, Class<?> next, boolean doRedirect) {
        super(context);
        this.doRedirect = doRedirect;
        setNext(next);
    }

    public boolean isDoRedirect() {
        return doRedirect;
    }

    public void setDoRedirect(boolean doRedirect) {
        this.doRedirect = doRedirect;
    }

    @Override
    protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
        Form requestHeaders = (Form) request.getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");

        if ((requestHeaders.getValues("x-forwarded-proto") != null) && (requestHeaders.getValues("x-forwarded-proto").indexOf("https") != 0)) {
            if (doRedirect) {
                String target = "https://" + request.getHostRef().getHostDomain() + request.getResourceRef().getPath();
                Redirector redirector = new Redirector(getContext(), target, Redirector.MODE_CLIENT_SEE_OTHER);
                redirector.handle(request, response);
                return STOP;
            }
            else {
                response.setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_FORBIDDEN);
                return STOP;
            }
        }

        return CONTINUE;
    }

}
```

To use the SecureFilter, simply wrap the route / resource mappings:

```
    router.attach("/secure", new SecureFilter(getContext(), HelloSecureResource.class));
    router.attach("/secureWithRedirect", new SecureFilter(getContext(), HelloSecureResource.class, true));
```

Comment: This is fine for handling one or two calls, but my API has at least a dozen resources, all of which accept at least one method (most accept more). I would like to do this in one place, rather than everywhere where I handle a call.

Comment: Do you know if RESTlet has a global interceptor / filter?

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. It has a Redirector class, but I don't see how to use that to accomplish what I want. Perhaps I can use a "org.restlet.service.Service", but, again, not clear how.

Comment: I figured this out.  Check out the [SecureFilter](https://github.com/jamesward/restlet-template/blob/ssl_verify/src/main/java/com/jamesward/restlet/SecureFilter.java) and the [HelloApplication](https://github.com/jamesward/restlet-template/blob/ssl_verify/src/main/java/com/jamesward/restlet/HelloApplication.java) examples I just added to the `ssl_verify` branch of my [restlet-template example project](https://github.com/jamesward/restlet-template/tree/ssl_verify).

Comment: Thanks James. Gonna look into this!

Comment: Okay, your solution def works and works great. Two minor problems: 1. the SecureFilter does not pass context to the super constructor, so any resources routed to it are context-less (meaning they will have errors if they try to access form data, attributes, logs etc.). 2. generally, you DON'T want secure access when running locally, so the SecureFilter class should have a parameter that controls whether or not is actually does anything. But those are trivial to fix.If you update your answer or post a new answer I will mark it correct. Thanks a TON!

Comment: Cool.  1. I've added Context to the constructors.  2. This situation is already handled.  If the `x-forwarded-proto` header isn't present then the filter just continues.  I'll update the answer.